# Are the 2005 & newer Doctor Who scripts all new material?

Tags: doctor-who

Are the 2005 & newer episodes of [Doctor Who](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b006q2x0) fresh scripts, or were some of the scripts from older seasons rewritten for new viewer education since the Doctor Who series rebooted?

Comment: Its not an actual reboot, I just continued. Sort of.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

None of them are direct rewrites of older TV episodes, but some of them are rewrites of expanded universe material written by the same authors. For example:

- The "Human Nature"/"Family of Blood" two-parter from season 3 started as a tie-in novel also called *Human Nature*.
- "A Christmas Carol", the season 5 Christmas episode, is a reworking of Steven Moffat's earlier short story "Continuity Errors."
- "The Lodger," also from season 5, may or may not qualify -- it's a rewritten version of a comic strip, but the original comic strip was already post-reboot.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of stories from the new TV series were rewritten from [Big Finish](http://bigfinish.com/) audio stories as well:

- "Dalek" was adapted from "Jubilee"
- "The Age of Steel"/"Rise of the Cybermen" were inspired by "Spare Parts"